# Do you bring to mind the specific time and place when you use the Past Verb?

Tags: grammar

I've been thinking about it for a while but couldn't come up with how I should ask this. They always say like the Present Perfect is for the unspecific, unknown times or several actions in the past. I mean, at least they say when you use Present Perfect, you don't need to bring up the specific precise time. Then, on the contrary, when you use the Past Tense, do you ALWAYS bring to mind any specific point in your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider:

> I *went* to school in London.

That implies that, at some point during your schooling, it was in London.

> I *didn't like* that film.

You saw the film some time in the past, and didn't like it. Maybe several times. Maybe you don't remember when.

> I hated English lessons.

When you had English lessons - any time you had English lessons - you hated them.

The simple aspect - as found in the past simple and present simple - is used, among other things, for statements of general truth or statements regarding habitual or recurrent actions.